# Syntax Err GET on an Apple II, AppleDOS 3.3 using Applesoft

Tags: basic, apple-ii

I am using the AppleWin emulator, setup as an Apple IIe, Apple DOS 3.3 with Applesoft. My goal is to make a simple game.

This simple GET program works fine at the `]` prompt (I am not sure, but I think it's called the monitor).

```
10 GET V$
20 PRINT V$
```

It prints the pressed key as expected

Then I start Applesoft using `LOAD APPLESOFT`. I tried writing the same simple program than at the `]` prompt. But this time when I type the first line `10 GET V$` I get as output `*** SYNTAX ERR`.

I think it's not a supported feature, but in the ApplesoftII Basic Programming Reference Manual they list get a reserved keyword.

I could update to a higher version of Applesoft, then which version of Applebasic would support it?
I can also use another method of getting a key press without the user needing to press enter afterwards.

Comment: Applesoft errors begin with a question mark. `*** SYNTAX ERR` means that you're still in integer basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to research my issue, I have found the location of memory for the keyboard buffer.

The keyboard buffer is `-16384` and the way to reset that value of that address is to access `-16368`.

If the value in `-16384` is larger than 128 then a key has been pressed.
So, I can use `PEEK -16384` to read the value. To get an ASCII code you need to subtract 128 to that value.
Example code:

```
KEY= PEEK(-16384)
IF KEY>=128 THEN PRINT KEY-128
```

To tell the system you dealt with the key press and reset the value, you need to access the value in `-16368`. By using `PEEK or POKE`.
Example code:

```
POKE -16368,0

Or can also be PEEKed
PRINT PEEK -16368
```

Answer (score 0):

Applesoft on the Apple ][e (the first apple version to support lower-case at all) is case sensitive, and all the keywords are UPPERCASE only -- so `get` will not match the keyword (or anything) and will give you a syntax error.

Of course, if you're emulating an original Apple ][, there's no lower case at all, and lower case letters show up as flashing uppercase -- and still won't match a keyword.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I meant `GET` in upper case. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

if the error you are getting is *** SYNTAX ERR and not "?SYNTAX ERROR" then you are using integer basic and not applesoft basic. Try to switch to applesoft basic first by using FP